# Linked Data Structures: Restricting a link operation

Tags: alloy

I have a model (see below) with two signatures: `Data` and `Node`.  I have defined some predicates which characterise inhabitants of Node, namely: `Orphan`, `Terminal`, and `Isolated`.

What I want to do - but have not yet achieved - is to define a predicate `Link` which models the linking of two Node such that one Node becomes the successor (`succ`) of the other.  Moreover, I would like to restrict the operation such that links can only be made to `Isolated` Nodes.  Furthermore, I would like the restriction - if it is possible - to somehow be *internal to the `Link` predicate*.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
sig Data {}

sig Node {
    data: Data,
    succ: lone Node
}

// Node characterisation
pred Isolated (n: Node) { Orphan[n] and Terminal[n] }

pred Orphan (n: Node) { no m: Node | m.succ = n }

pred Terminal (n: Node) { no n.succ }


/*
 * Link
 * 
 * May only Link n to an m, when:
 *  - n differs from m
 *  - m is an Isolated Node (DOES NOT WORK)
 *
 * After the operation: 
 *  - m is the succcessor of n
 */
pred Link (n,m: Node) {
    n != m
    Isolated[m] /* Not satisfiable */
    m = succ[n]
}

pred LinkFeasible { some n,m: Node | Link[n,m] }

run LinkFeasible
```

Including the conjunct `Isolated[m]` renders the model unsatisfiable.  I think I understand why: there can be no `Node` which is both `Isolated` *and* a successor of another.  I include it only in the hope that it might reveal my intentions.

My question: how do I define the `Link` predicate to link two Nodes such that only `Isolated` nodes may be linked-to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want Link to be an *operation* which changes the value of `succ`. In order to model change in Alloy, you need to add an ordered signature which represents the distinct states of your system. So your signature would look something like this:

```
open util/ordering[time]

sig Time {}
sig Data {}

sig Node {
    data: Data,
    succ: Node lone -> Time
}
```

But this also changes all of your predicates. You can't say that a node is isolated or terminal, you can only say that a node is isolated at time `T`.

If you have *Software Abstractions*, this is all covered in section 6.1. I'm not familiar with any good guides to modeling time in Alloy outside of that book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I believe it will work nicely.  I own a copy of _Software Abstractions_, but I haven't absorbed it yet (clearly).  I had wondered whether it was possible to order Nodes in a manner similar to the Book ordering in section 2.4.  Then the Node signature might not need to change.  Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Adam I don't think so. In 2.4 is using a "pun" of sorts: the model has only one book, so we can use multiple books to represent a single book changing. Here has many nodes, so we can't use "more nodes" to represent those multiple nodes changing.